# non-trainable model taking longer time for inference than trainable model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a trained model in saved model format. I made this model non-trainable by setting `model.trainable=False` and verified in the `model.summary()` that all parameters are non-trainable. This helps to reduce the model size on disk and faster load times

I have saved this non-trainable model to disk, then I am loading non-trainable model and using it for inference purpose, there is no change in accuracy of model.

When I time using `time.time()`, inference from the non-trainable model vs trainable model(with trainable parameters), on the exact same dataset, the original trainable model seems to perform faster than non-trainable model

Can anyone shed some light as to why the non-trainable model performs slower than trainable model. I am using `tensorflow 2.4.1` `python3.7`